# How to cancel insert in listview following method asp.net vb

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, listview

I am stumped by being unable to cancel a list view insert operation following a method to validate a string.   While the method validates the string and shows a modal popup when the string is not valid, then I want to stop the insert using e.cancel in listviewinserteventargs, however the cancel operation did not occur.  Any help is appreciated!!!

```
Imports System.Data
'Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class SecureOrderHCTPScan
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Public iPreLoadIndex As Integer
    'Public pageContent As String = "<!-- #include file=""content/home/home.txt"" -->"

    Dim currentOrderID As Int32 'for current order number
    Dim entryNum As Int32 ' holds sample entry number


    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        gotoDefaultHome.HRef = "TestOrderDefault.aspx"
        gotoDefaultHome.Title = ""

        iPreLoadIndex = CInt(Request.QueryString("titrateIdx"))

        'creates new order object
        Dim orderTicket = New orderNumbers

        'checks to see if an order # has been issued and if so, does not create a new order
        If (Me.IsPostBack) Then

        Else
            ViewState("currentOrderID") = orderTicket.createNewOrder("BSIRG6789")
        End If
        currentOrderID = ViewState("currentOrderID")
        orderNumLbl.Text = currentOrderID
        Session("orderNum") = currentOrderID

        'Verify Date in tbxColDate as being no more than than 7 days old and not in the future
        Dim currentDate As Date = DateTime.Now()
        Dim tubeDumpDate As Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7)

        'set maximum and minimum dates for date validation, date is time specimens are kept
        'in lab
        tbxCollDate_Validator.MaximumValue = currentDate.ToString("MM/dd/yy")
        tbxCollDate_Validator.MinimumValue = tubeDumpDate.ToString("MM/dd/yy")

        'The number of tubes scanned in this session
        'create new entry number generator object
        Dim entryNum = New entryNumber
        Session("EntryNum") = entryNum.createNextEntryNum(currentOrderID)

        'Exit Sub
        'homeContent.Text = "<!-- #include file=""content/home/home.txt"" -->"
        'Response.Write("about page...<br />")
        'Response.Write(Request.Form("contentIdx") & "....<br />")
        'Response.Write(contentIdxSS.Value)

    End Sub


    Sub insert(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ListViewInsertEventArgs)

        Dim tb = New TextBox
        Dim donorNumString As String
        Dim barcodeValidFlg As Boolean = True

        'gets donor number from listview control
        tb = ListView1.InsertItem.FindControl("donorNumTextBox")

        donorNumString = tb.Text

        'tb.Text = donorNumString.ToLower

        Dim validBarcode = New BETAbarcodeValidator(donorNumString)

        validBarcode.validate(donorNumString)
        barcodeValidFlg = validBarcode.BarcodeValid

        If (barcodeValidFlg = False) Then
            e.Cancel = True
            Button3_ModalPopupExtender.Show()

        End If
    End Sub


    Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    End Sub



        <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" 
            DataKeyNames="donorNum" 
            DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
            InsertItemPosition="FirstItem" 
            EnableModelValidation="True">

            <AlternatingItemTemplate>
                <tr style="background-color: #FFFFFF;color: #284775;">
                    <td>
                        <asp:Button ID="DeleteButton" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" CausesValidation="False" 
                            Text="Delete" />
                    </td>
                    <td class="testSelection">
                        <asp:Label ID="entryNumLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("entryNum") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td class="donorNumberTbxEntryCell">
                        <asp:Label ID="donorNumLabel" runat="server"
                            Text='<%# Eval("donorNum") %>' />
                    </td>

                    <td class="testSelection">
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="CHGCheckBox" runat="server" Checked='<%# Eval("CHG") %>' 
                            Enabled="false" />
                    </td>
                    <td class="testSelection">
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="CMVCheckBox" runat="server" Checked='<%# Eval("CMV") %>' 
                            Enabled="false" />
                    </td>
                    <td class="testSelection">
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="devHCTPCheckBox" runat="server" 
                            Checked="true" Enabled="false" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </AlternatingItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <tr style="background-color: #999999;">
                    <td>
                        <asp:Button ID="UpdateButton" runat="server" CommandName="Update" 
                            Text="Update" />
                        <asp:Button ID="CancelButton" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" 
                            Text="Cancel" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="entryNumTextBox" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Bind("entryNum") %>' />
                    </td>


                    <td class="donorNumberTbxEntryCell">
                        <asp:Label ID="donorNumLabel1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("donorNum") %>' />
                    </td>

                    <td class="testSelection">
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="CHGCheckBox" runat="server" Checked='<%# Bind("CHG") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td class="testSelection">
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="CMVCheckBox" runat="server" Checked='<%# Bind("CMV") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td class="testSelection">
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="devHCTPCheckBox" runat="server" 
                            Checked="true" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <EmptyDataTemplate>
                <table runat="server" 
                    style="background-color: #FFFFFF;border-collapse: collapse;border-color: #999999;border-style:none;border-width:1px;">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            No data was returned.</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </EmptyDataTemplate>
            <InsertItemTemplate>
                <tr style="">
                    <td>
                        <asp:Button ID="InsertButton" runat="server" CommandName="Insert" 
                            Text="Save" />
                        <asp:Button ID="CancelButton" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" 
                            Text="Clear" />
                    </td>
                    <td class="testSelection">
                        <asp:label ID="entryNumTextBox" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Bind("entryNum") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td class="donorNumberTbxEntryCell">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="donorNumTextBox" class="donorNumTbxEntry" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Bind("donorNum") %>' />
                    </td>

                    <td class="testSelection">
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="CHGCheckBox" runat="server" Checked='<%# Bind("CHG") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td class="testSelection">
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="CMVCheckBox" runat="server" Checked='<%# Bind("CMV") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td class="testSelection">
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="devHCTPCheckBox" runat="server" 
                            Checked="true" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </InsertItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr style="background-color: #E0FFFF;color: #333333;">
                    <td>
                        <asp:Button ID="DeleteButton" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" CausesValidation="False"  
                            Text="Delete" />
                    </td>
                    <td class="testSelection">
                        <asp:Label ID="entryNumLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("entryNum") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="donorNumLabel" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Eval("donorNum") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td class="testSelection">
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="CHGCheckBox" runat="server" Checked='<%# Eval("CHG") %>' 
                            Enabled="false" />
                    </td>
                    <td class="testSelection">
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="CMVCheckBox" runat="server" Checked='<%# Eval("CMV") %>' 
                            Enabled="false" />
                    </td>
                    <td class="testSelection">
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="devHCTPCheckBox" runat="server" 
                            Checked="true" Enabled="false" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <LayoutTemplate>
                <table runat="server">
                    <tr runat="server">
                        <td runat="server">
                            <table ID="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" border="1" 
                                style="background-color: #FFFFFF;border-collapse: collapse;border-color: #999999;border-style:none;border-width:1px;font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
                                <tr runat="server" style="background-color: #E0FFFF;color: #333333;">
                                    <th runat="server">
                                    </th>
                                    <th runat="server">
                                        #</th>
                                    <th runat="server">
                                        Donor Number</th>
                                    <th runat="server">
                                        CHG</th>
                                    <th runat="server">
                                        CMV</th>
                                    <th runat="server">
                                        HCTP</th>
                                </tr>
                                <tr ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server">
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr runat="server">
                        <td runat="server" 
                            style="text-align: center;background-color: #5D7B9D;font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;color: #FFFFFF">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </LayoutTemplate>
            <SelectedItemTemplate>
                <tr style="background-color: #E2DED6;font-weight: bold;color: #333333;">
                    <td>
                        <asp:Button ID="DeleteButton" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" CausesValidation="False" 
                            Text="Delete" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="entryNumLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("entryNum") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="donorNumLabel" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Eval("donorNum") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td class="testSelection">
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="CHGCheckBox" runat="server" Checked='<%# Eval("CHG") %>' 
                            Enabled="false" />
                    </td>
                    <td class="testSelection">
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="CMVCheckBox" runat="server" Checked='<%# Eval("CMV") %>' 
                            Enabled="false" />
                    </td>
                    <td class="testSelection">
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="devHCTPCheckBox" runat="server" 
                            Checked="true" Enabled="false" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </SelectedItemTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>


    <p class="style1" />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit Order" />
    </td>

</tr>
</table>

<% If (iPreLoadIndex = 2) Then%>
   <script type="text/javascript">changeContent(1,2); </script>
<% ElseIf (iPreLoadIndex = 3) Then%>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
            DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [ctsTPAOrder] WHERE [donorNum] = @original_donorNum" 
            InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [ctsTPAOrder] ([entryNum], [donorNum], [orderID], [CHG], [CMV], [devHCTP]) VALUES (@entryNum, @donorNum, @orderID, @CHG, @CMV, 1)" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT [entryNum], [donorNum], [CHG], [CMV], [devHCTP] FROM [ctsTPAOrder] WHERE ([orderID] = @orderID) ORDER BY [entryNum] DESC" 
            UpdateCommand="UPDATE [ctsTPAOrder] SET [entryNum] = @entryNum, [CHG] = @CHG, [CMV] = @CMV, [devHCTP] = @devHCTP WHERE [donorNum] = @original_donorNum" 
            OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}">
            <DeleteParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="original_donorNum" Type="String" />
            </DeleteParameters>
            <InsertParameters>
                <asp:ControlParameter Name="orderID" ControlID="orderNumLbl" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:SessionParameter Name="entryNum" SessionField="entryNum" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="donorNum" Type="String" />
                <asp:ControlParameter Name="collectionDate" ControlID="tbxCollDate" Type="DateTime" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="CHG" Type="Boolean" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="CMV" Type="Boolean" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="devHCTP" Type="Boolean" />
            </InsertParameters>
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:SessionParameter Name="orderID" SessionField="orderNum" Type="Int32" />
            </SelectParameters>
            <UpdateParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="entryNum" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="CHG" Type="Boolean" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="CMV" Type="Boolean" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="devHCTP" Type="Boolean" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="original_donorNum" Type="String" />
                            <asp:ControlParameter Name="orderID" ControlID="orderNumLbl" Type="Int32" />
            </UpdateParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a handler for [OnItemInserting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.oniteminserting.aspx) and [Cancel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listviewinserteventargs.aspx) the operation there.